# How to merge multiple objects into one, in gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have performed union in my query which gives me the following output

```
{
    key1 = value1,
    key2 = value2
},
{
    key3 = value3
}
```

I need output as follows,

```
{
    key1 = value1,
    key2 = value2,
    key3 = value3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deconstruct and reconstruct the maps. This operation is described in some detail in [Gremlin Recipes](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#collections) if you want to read more.

The following code gets you to the position of your `union()`:

```
gremlin> x = [[key1:"value1",key2:"value2"],[key3:"value3"]]
==>[key1:value1,key2:value2]
==>[key3:value3]
gremlin> g.inject(x).unfold()
==>[key1:value1,key2:value2]
==>[key3:value3]
```

Then you just `unfold()` those maps to map entries (i.e. key/value pairs) and `group()` them back together:

```
gremlin> g.inject(x).unfold().unfold().group().by(keys).by(values)
==>[key1:[value1],key2:[value2],key3:[value3]]
gremlin> g.inject(x).unfold().unfold().group().by(keys).by(select(values))
==>[key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3]
```

Comment: Thanks, **unfold().unfold().group().by(keys).by(select(values))** works!